# How to hide controls from webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a video url and i have shown it in webview now the video from url shows download button in webview and i don't want to show it in my webview, is there any way to hide such type of buttons

Comment: video can't show any `download button`. I think that you are showing a web page in your webView. And that web page has some button.

Comment: use a tool like dev-tools on the page. find the element - either the parent of the DL-button or the button itself. modify the display to "none"

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes you got my point, is there any solution??

Comment: maybe, but it depends on your code, and web page code. Basically, run JS in your WebView to find and remove the HTML that you want to remove.

Comment: Ok i will try to do so

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? @YoLo